# Why bidirectional mapping fails with empty relationship

Tags: java, hibernate, one-to-many, many-to-one

Following are my two related tables

```
public class VProduct{
    @Id
    @Column(name="product_id")
    private Long productId;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="vProduct", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade={CascadeType.REMOVE})
    private Set<ProductPan> pans;
}

public class ProductPan {
    @Id
    @Column(name="product_pan_id")
    private Long productPanId;

    @Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
    @ManyToOne(optional=true, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name="product_id", referencedColumnName = "product_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)  
    private VProduct vProduct;
}
```

I get the following exception when i try to query the VProduct tabel.

```
org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: ERROR: column pans0_.product_pan_id does not exist
```

What am i doing wrong here ? At the moment ProductPan table is empty. And its not guranteed to have any items for a VProduct. if thats the problem is there any annotation i can add to ignore that null data problem ?

This is the hibernate query and result

```
14:39:49,994 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) Hibernate: select pans0_.product_id as product3_101_1_, pans0_.product_pan_id as product1_1_, pans0_.product_pan_id as product1_71_0_, pans0_.pan_id as pan2_71_0_, pans0_.product_id as product3_71_0_ from product_pan pans0_ where pans0_.product_id=?
14:39:50,113 WARN  [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 42703
14:39:50,116 ERROR [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) ERROR: column pans0_.product_pan_id does not exist
```

Comment: Do you have column `product_pan_id` in table `productpan`?

Comment: Can you print out the SQL that is failing, to check where is hibernate searching for `product_pan_id` column? Before that, a quick check, try removing `updateable = false, removable = false` and see if it works without it.

Comment: updated question with hibernate output

Comment: Sorry for asking obvious things, but when you run that SQL directly  on your database, it works? If yes, it is quite strange. Maybe some other query is causing the problem? In your question you wrote that you are querying `VProduct` table, but that table isn't mentioned in this SQL, so it might be that the problem is elsewhere.

Comment: Can you post the hibernate code which fetch the data

Comment: @dinesh707, If you have a column in DB that matches with your `product_pan_id` then check the case of the letters because some databases are case sensitive.

Comment: i did a work around to fix this issue. I made it lazy and i do a fetch join which gives me what i want. But still no idea why this is happening. Thank you all for help